# sudo from PHP, blank result

Tags: php, security, sudo, sudoers

I'm trying to run sudo script from php.
Added it to sudoers, from CLI everything work as expected.

However, running from apache (mod-itk) I'm getting blank result.
Tried to add `!requiretty` to sudoers, didn't help.

`system('whoami')` from same php script returns `blogs3`.

all my modifications in sudoers:

```
blogs3 ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/virtualhost.sh
ALL ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL #just for test, didn't help anyway

Defaults!/usr/local/bin/virtualhost.sh !requiretty
Defaults    !requiretty
Defaults:blogs3 !requiretty
```

Any ideas how to make it work?

Comment: How are you trying to run sudo from Php. Do you mean you are trying to run your Php script with sudo command. Please give an example

Comment: <? system("sudo /usr/local/bin/virtualhost.sh"); ?>

Comment: from CLI it's OK, running from blogs3 user

Comment: Try to add this line to your /etc/sudoers file: blog3 ALL=(ALL) ALL. It will allow blog3 user to run all commands from all terminals as all users. If that works then you can replace the last AND with the command:  /usr/local/bin/virtualhost.sh

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion pal. There is no problem to run script from terminal, problem comes from apache. As I mentioned above, 'from CLI everything work as expected'.

However I tried to implement your solution, no changes - still blank result.